# Magento2: I need to get shipping address and Billing address after updated from admin with this event sales_order_address_save_after

Tags: magento2

I am stuck with this event `sales_order_address_save_after`.

When I update the address from Magento admin then not able to differentiate billing address and shipping address.

Anyone have an idea for the same?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please define what magento version you are referring?

Comment: @RahulBarot 2.3.3

Comment: I have searched in vendor and didn't find such event.

Comment: Can you please share how I can do with another event as per my requirements?

Comment: Okay, sharing in some time

Answer (score 0):

Below controller is responsible for processing admin order address update form

`Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AddressSave`

In the `execute` method it loads the address using address_id passed as post data. You can get the type of the address using below code on the address object.

```
$address->getAddressType()
```

There is also one event is dispatched `admin_sales_order_address_update` but it just passes order_id to observer.

So you can write preference to override the execute method of the controller and modify it according to your need, you can add your logic in preference or modify event data and pass address_id to it and then load address in observer and add custom logic in the observer.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event <event name=""sales_order_address_save_after""> in which order id already stored (if you need it). Just check is it billing or shipping address:

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
/** @see \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::_getEventData() */
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address $address */
$address = $event->getDataObject();
/** @var int $orderId */
$orderId = $address->getParentId();
$addressType = $address->getAddressType();

switch ($addressType) {
    case Address::TYPE_BILLING:
        // Do something with billing address
        break;
    case Address::TYPE_SHIPPING:
        // Do something with shipping address
        break;
    default:
        /**
         * This is a not usual case, when address type is not in one of this types: billing or shipping
         */
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am checking and will update you soon once done